# react-native-image-slider-box not working as expected

Tags: react-native

When I try to implement react-native-image-slider-box with text overlay with an absolute value, the sliding functionality stops. When I remove the absolute value (and the text does not overlay on the image) the sliding functionality returns. It also has no marginRight or paddingRight. Am I doing something wrong in the below code?

```
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <SliderBox
            images={match.images}
            sliderBoxHeight={200}
            onCurrentImagePressed={(index) =>
              console.warn(`image ${index} pressed`)
            }
            parentWidth={width}
            ImageComponentStyle={{
              height: Constant.height * 0.4,
              borderRadius: 24,
              borderWidth: 2,
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <View
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            height: 300,
            width: "100%",
          }}>
          <View style={styles.imageRow}>
            <BoldText style={styles.imagetitle}>{fullName}</BoldText>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.imageRow}>
            <Image source={locationIcon} style={styles.locationIcon} />
            <RegularText style={styles.subtitle}>
              {currentLocation[0].name}
            </RegularText>
          </View>
        </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell based on the information you provided, but my first guess would be that your text overlay view is resting on top the slider and preventing the slider from moving. To troubleshoot, I would recommend setting a background color for the text overlay container to check if that's the case. If so, reposition/resize the overlay text container.